# CruiseControl Failed Build Recovery

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Cruiscontrol sometimes can't connect to the repository and build fails. Is there a way that I can have cruisecontrol try to build again automatically when something like this happens????? In other words, I want cruisecontrol to keep building when it fails until build is successful...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Java version or .NET?

If the Java version use [buildafterfailed=true](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#project).